# kill process by its own description

Tags: windows, powershell, process

I need help for killing putty.exe by searching process for it's  description even if the user change the name and the class name ( win title ) for the putty.exe

```
if process description on process list = SSH, Telnet and Relogin client  

then kill putty.exe or whatever they named it
```

Can I do this from a cmd using powershell or wmic?

Comment: Because this is about how to manipulate user processes in Windows, migrating to SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be achieved by the following PowerShell command:

```
(get-process | ? {$_.Description -eq "SSH, Telnet and Rlogin Client"}).kill()
```

in Detail:

- `Get-Process` is used to receive a list of all running processes.
- `where-object {}` alias `? {}` is used to query all objects for your desired process description and selects all objects where the description equals the string.
- the `.kill()` method kills the selected process.

Note that this will only work on an elevated PowerShell, otherwise you won't be able to read the description of most processes because of permission issues and your where-object query will never find anything.

Comment: it gives me this error :
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock] doe
sn't contain a method named 'kill'.
At line:1 char:74
+ get-process | ? {$_.Description -eq "Sysinternals Process Explorer"}.kill <<<
< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (kill:String) [], RuntimeExcep
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: @QassamMahmoud looks like you forgot to wrap your command into () and also forgot () after .kill - your command should be like this: `(get-process | ? {$_.Description -eq "Sysinternals Process Explorer"}).kill()`